# SQLITE not working with Codeigniter in Exeoutput4PHP

Tags: sqlite, codeigniter, web-applications, exe

In my Codeigntier Project under EXEOUTPUT4PHP, I have set databse.php file as below:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'    => '',
    'hostname' => '',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => '../dbname.db',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlite3',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

In PHP Settings-> PHP Extensions option of EXEOUTPUT4PHP, I have compiled php_pdo_sqlite.dll and php_sqlite3.dll into exe

In PHP.ini, I have uncommented the lines: extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll and extension=php_sqlite3.dll

Still on running the application, I am getting the following error:

```
#### An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Class 'SQLite3' not found

Filename: EXELocation\Data\system\database\drivers\sqlite3\sqlite3_driver.php

Line Number: 89

Backtrace:

File: EXELocation\Data\application\models\User_model.php
Line: 6
Function: database

File: EXELocation\Data\application\controllers\User.php
Line: 8
Function: model

File: EXELocation\Data\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```